# Pagination not working on Post name permalink but working on plain permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to loop through a post type called blog. The pagination works fine when the Wordpress permalinks are set to plain however when I change it to post the name and click to go on pagination link, it loads a 404 error.

I found out that you can't have the same post type and page name since it will cause a 404 error. I wanted to know if there was a workaround because changing the name of the post type will affect the blog posts.

My page-blog.php

```
 <?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'blog',
                             'posts_per_page' => 2,
                             'paged'          => $paged,
                            'has_archive' => false,
                            'rewrite'     => array(
                                             'slug'       => '/blog', // if you need slug
                                             'with_front' => false,
                                             ),)
);
if ( $loop->have_posts() ):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        // Set variables
              $title = get_the_title();
              $post_date = get_the_date('M j');
              $amount_of_time_to_read = get_field('amount_of_time_to_read');     

    ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-blog-link">
        <div class="post">
           <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
            <div class="post-image-v2" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $url ?>');">
            </div>
            <div class="post-content-v2">
                <h2 class="post-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                <div class="post-excerpt">
                    <p><?php echo get_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>
                <p class="post-date"> <span class="caps"><?php echo $post_date; ?></span> | <?php echo $amount_of_time_to_read; ?>min read</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>

    <!--

                     -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <center>
    <div class="pagination mt-25">
        <?php pagination_bar( $loop ); ?>
    </div>
        </center>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
endif;

?>
```

My functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    foreach ($wp_post_types as $wp_post_type) {
        if ($wp_post_type->_builtin) continue;
        if (!$wp_post_type->has_archive && isset($wp_post_type->rewrite) && isset($wp_post_type->rewrite['with_front']) && !$wp_post_type->rewrite['with_front']) {
            $slug = (isset($wp_post_type->rewrite['slug']) ? $wp_post_type->rewrite['slug'] : $wp_post_type->name);
            $page = get_page_by_slug($slug);
            if ($page) add_rewrite_rule('^' .$slug .'/page/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=' .$page->ID .'&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
        }
    }
}

function get_page_by_slug($page_slug, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $page = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s AND post_status = 'publish'", $page_slug, $post_type ) );

    return ($page ? get_post($page, $output) : NULL);
}
```

Comment: you can't have the same page name as your post type name. if you can't change the post type name then change the page name.

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar still would not work because the URL of the page will be /blogs and the custom post type slug will be /blog.

Comment: so you want to keep the page name and post type name same and want pagination working?  you can use rewrite rule to make it work. i haven't used it but take a look at this "https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135146/resolve-a-custom-post-type-name-vs-page-permalink-conflict-same-slug" May be it will help you.

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar thank you the answer was there. THANK YOU, BROTHER!

Comment: Happy to Help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to achieve to have a Post Type and Page to be of the same slug?

As per my understanding you want to display the archive of your custom post type "Blog". All you have to do is create a file name archive-blog.php and use the plain WordPress loop. That way you don't need to have a page-blog.php (Delete it) to display the Archives of your "Blog" post type. yourwebsite.com/blog will automatically display your "Blog" archive.

Use the code below to paste in your archive-blog.php

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

// set vars
$amount_of_time_to_read = get_field('amount_of_time_to_read');

?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="post-blog-link">
    <div class="post">
       <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        <div class="post-image-v2" style="background-image:url( '<?php echo $url ?>' );">
        </div>
        <div class="post-content-v2">
            <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <p class="post-date"> <span class="caps"><?php the_date( 'M j' ); ?></span> | <?php echo $amount_of_time_to_read; ?>min read</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </a>

<?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php 
// You need to tweak this function, it shouldn't be needing a $loop var to work
// paste the function here and may be we will take a look at that
// pagination_bar( $loop ); 

the_posts_pagination();

?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php // No Posts Found ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Had to add this to my functions.php

```
add_rewrite_rule('^blog/page/([0-9]+)','index.php?pagename=blog&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Comment: complete site stopped working. Got the critical error msg